# Disable user_deny.db in Cyrus/imapd

Tags: linux, debian, imap, pop3, cyrus

We have a `cyrus 2.4.12` on Debian, we use packages, rather than building each software ourselves.

I am getting the this "log" constantly, a lot of, various users, and 8-10 times per user request:

> fetching user_deny.db entry for 'user123'

I have searched for it, but haven't found a real solution, there were [some patches](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.mail.imap.cyrus/33293) for 2.3.xx, but we don't want ot build it, we prefer to use packages.

Is there any solution to disable the `user_deny.db` at all. We don't need this feature. It wastes the CPU as disk.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to [`syslog-ng`](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng) and filter out this message by configuring:

`filter f_imapd { facility(local6) and level(debug) and not match("regexp" value("fetching user_deny.db entry for")); };`

Answer (score 0):

If you use syslog-ng, you can also try suppress identical messages with suppress configuration option:

```
options {
 suppress(30);
};
```

In this example identical messages will be logged once per every 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Seems the correct filter syntax is:

```
filter f_imapd { facility(local6) and not match("fetching user_deny.db entry for" value("MESSAGE")); };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution to the problem. Create a (new) `user_deny.db` from an (empty) flat file with `cvt_cyrusdb` and the messages will disappear.

https://www.cyrusimap.org/~vanmeeuwen/imap/admin/sop-userdeny.html

Answer (score 0):

cyrus-imapd sends all levels of messages (debug, info, warnings, error), and cannot disconnect or change the level of messages. It's reported in bugzilla in 2011, but they don't seem to be interested in fixing it, so messages can't be disconnected. To remove them from the log, they can be intercepted from rsyslog.

To do it, create a file in /etc/rsyslog.d such as:

```
vi /etc/rsyslog.d/fetching_user_deny_error.conf
```

Add this to the file:

```
if $programname == 'cyrus' and $msg contains_i 'fetching user_deny' then ~
```

To finish restart rsyslog:

```
service rsyslog restart
```